# how to take two values from single button using query string

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, session, query-string

I assinged two values in button click. when the page is redirecting the 2 values will pass. But in page i don't know how to take a second value using query string..

```
<a href="<%: Url.Action("Index", "Test", new { planId = "500" ,validity="120"}) %>"><a>

<% var value = string.Empty;
      var value1 = string.Empty;
       if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
       {
           value = Request.QueryString[0];
           Session["PlanId"] = value;
       }
       else if (Request.QueryString.Count>0)
       {
           value1 = Request.QueryString[3];
           Session["Validity"] = value1;
       }%>
```

PlanId is taking the value. but validity is not taking the value.. Please help me how to do?

Comment: Request.QueryString[3]; is this having value

Comment: no.i dont know how to assign the second value. that's why i take like this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is another way to solve this problem instead of using QueryString collection.

Say if you have URL like this -

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Test", "Model" , new { planid="RAT500" ,validity="120" })">hi<a>
```

Then have corresponding action like this -

```
public class ModelController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Test(string planid, string validity)
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

And when you click the link, your values will be there in the parameters as shown below -

[image]

And say you have other QueryStrings as shown below -

```
<a href="@Url.Action("Test", "Model" , new { planid="RAT500" ,validity="120", name = "rami"})">hi<a>
```

Then you can get other QueryString as shown below -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's an `else if` so if the first `if` is true, it'll skip `else if`. It should be as follows:

```
 <% var value = string.Empty;
    var value1 = string.Empty;
    if (Request.QueryString.Count > 0)
    {
        value = Request.QueryString[0];
        Session["PlanId"] = value;
    }

    if (Request.QueryString.Count > 3)
    {
        value1 = Request.QueryString[3];
        Session["Validity"] = value1;
    } %>
```

Comment: can u please tell `Request.QueryString[0];` what will put in index?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the issue is, but the second test should be checking Count > 3, not Count > 0.

Answer (score 0):

[QueryString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be indexed by names directly - would be easier to read (and avoid getting elements outside of the string):

```
  var planId = Request.QueryString["planId"];      
  var validity = Request.QueryString["validity"];
```

Comment: if i put like this i received planid value only for both.. what will do?

Comment: @Duk - what is the url of page for the second part of example (I assume `...Url.Action...` belong to first page and the second part belong to next page). Side note: you should be doing that manipulation of query string in controller, preferably as action parameters and pass via model)

Comment: when i redirect to index page it is taking the value of planid and validity. On that index page i am taking and assign the query string. wherever i want to pass the variable values i use that query string variables.. but i am getting planid only. i cant take the validity.

Comment: @Duk please edit your post and add comment with exact value of `Request.RawUrl` next to each chunk of code.